# pivot_longer across multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a plot database with multiple attribute values per tree. Currently the database is wide with one row per plot and tree1_name, tree1_dbh, tree1_use etc. I would like to have one row per tree, but I just cannot get pivot_longer to work for me.

Test data

```
test <- data_frame(c("Abc", "Cde", "Efg"), c(10,15,20),c(15,20,25), c(1,0,1))
test <- cbind(c("Plot1","Plot2","Plot3"),test,test[3:1,])
names(test) <- c("Plot_n","Tree1_spp","Tree1_dbh1","Tree1_dbh2","Tree1_planted_or_not","Tree2_spp","Tree2_dbh1","Tree2_dbh2","Tree2_planted_or_not")
```

I would like for the data to be arranged

Plot_n Spp dbh1 dbh2 Planted_or_not

Plot1 Tree1 ...

Plot1 Tree2 ...

Plot2 Tree1 ...

Plot2 Tree2...

I have been trying with

```
test %>%
        pivot_longer(
                cols = -Plot_n,
                names_to = c("tree", ".values"),
                names_pattern = "^([^_\n]+_).*(.*)"
        )
```

and many other regular expressions (which I do not understand). I am stuck working out if the regular expression is wrong or the use of pivot_longer

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. Two things that had to be fixed.

1. `.value` not `.values`
2. for the `name_pattern` argumemt you need to have your brackets around the two groups you are going to extract from each of your old columns names. The way I've got it done here, is that under column "tree", you will have all the alphanumeric characters before, `_`, and the rest of the column names will be everything that appeared after the `_`.

```
test %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Plot_n,
    names_to = c("tree", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "^([[:alnum:]]*)_(.*)"
  )
```

```
  Plot_n tree  spp    dbh1  dbh2 planted_or_not
  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Plot1  Tree1 Abc      10    15              1
2 Plot1  Tree2 Efg      20    25              1
3 Plot2  Tree1 Cde      15    20              0
4 Plot2  Tree2 Cde      15    20              0
5 Plot3  Tree1 Efg      20    25              1
6 Plot3  Tree2 Abc      10    15              1
```